# Java synchoronize on copy of object rather then the actual object

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

I am looking at the bluetooth chat example and I don't understand why in the code bellow it is syncronzed on a copy of the local ConnectedThread object. Surely r & mConnectedThread point to the same object?

```
public synchronized void write(byte[] out)
{
    // Create temporary object
    ConnectedThread r;

    // Synchronize a copy of the ConnectedThread
    synchronized (this)
    {

        if (mState != ICommsService.STATE_CONNECTED)
            return;

        r = mConnectedThread;
    }

    // Perform the write unsynchronized
    r.write(out);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not synchronized **on** the ConnectedThread object. It's synchronized on `this`, so that no other thread can modify `mState` and `mConnectedThread` when the current thread needs them.

The comment who is probably confusing you says that's it's synchronizing a copy of the `ConnectedThread` (that is, it makes the copy of the reference to the `ConnectedThread` and that the copy process is synchronized). The comment does not say that it is synchronizing **on** the copy of the `ConnectedThread`.

And the reason why the function puts the reference to the ConnectedThread object in a local variable `r` before using it is to be able to not synchronize the whole object when calling `write`, which can be a long action.

Comment: Many thanks for your reply. Yourr reply has made it clearer but I still don't understand what the difference is between calling mConnectedThread.write and r.write surely they reference the same object?

Comment: Yes they reference the same object. The thing is, you need to synchronize in some way so that the check on `mState` is not inconsistent with the value of `mConnectedThread`. One could have put the `write` function in the synchronized block itself, but it would have made other thread blocks while the `write` function completes, which can take a long time. The solution is to make a copy of the value of the variable and call `write` outside of the synchronized block.

Comment: That said, I realize now that the whole function is also synchronized, which makes the whole thing pointless. This may be a mistake.